# Understanding big O notation simplified function

Tags: asymptotics

Recently been looking into algorithms and trying to understand the big O notation. On the [wikipedia website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) it gives an example linked below to image in reference.

I'm struggling to understand why we can simplify the $-2x^3$ to $+2x^3$, and then on **line 2** why we can further simplify to $+2x^4 + 5x^4$ ? Thanks in advance for guidance! \

$| 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 | ≤ 6x^4 + | 2x^3 | + 5$ 
$| 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 | ≤ 6x^4 + 2x^4 + 5x^4$ 
$| 6x^4 - 2x^3 + 5 | ≤ 13x^4$

[wiki-big-o-notation-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixB6w.png) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Could you please directly add the stuff you are talking about in the form of text or image?

Comment: Apologies I would have included an image, however I do not have the required amount of points (10+) to upload an image. On the wikipedia page for big o notation it's the #Example section I'm referencing in the question. I've edited the text in my answer.

Comment: 1) The absolute value of a sum is known to be no greater than the sum of absolute values. 2) If $x>1$, then $x^3<x^4$ and  $5<5x^4$.

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee thank you for the article, really enjoyable read. Still struggling to understand the rules that allow us to simplify ($2x^4$ and $5x^4$)...might just be taking a while to sink in.

Comment: Asymptotics discusses what happens as inputs get larger, most constant factors are small enough that in a reasonable range they don't make the difference between classifications. $5x^4< x^5$ any time $x>5$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that makes sense, thanks! Also going to leave this link here in case it's useful to anyone else stumbling across big O notation for computer science https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is a triangle inequality:
$$
|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|.
$$

You haven't copied, and thus may have disregarded, some crucial text in the Wikipedia example you quote :

> [Prove] $f(x) \leq Mx^4$ for some suitable choice of $x_0$ and M and for all
> $x > x_0$. To prove this, let $x_0 = 1$ and $M = 13$.

With this in mind, you can understand the following steps, e.g. $2x^3 \leq 2x^4$... for $x > x_0$ of course.

Probably, what you haven't understood either, is the objective of all this: one wants to have a "simple" upper bound (written as $x$ to some power, here $x^4$) for $f(x)$ valid for all $x$ greater that some $x_0$, which will allow us to write that $f(x) = O(x^4)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

For functions of only one variable, it is in general not too difficult to determine which is the fastest growing term, then use a multiple of this term as a bound on each of the other terms. The sum of all these will be a certain number of times this fastest growing term ($M$ in the example), because this $M$ is a fixed constant this doesn't affect the behaviour of the function asymptotically, so one doesn't pay special attention to the actual value of this $M$. Which means that you can obtain the same optimal $O$ behaviour with more or less tight bounds on individual terms, as long as you have correctly identified the fastest growing one.

Comment: Your'e right, I missed the crucial parts missing the objective that is simplifying the function to the terms that grow most quickly (i.e. $x^4$). Please could you expand on why we can change $2x^3$ to $2x^4$, likewise with $5x^4$? For example, a different function if the upper bound is $7x^5$ with other products that have $x$ to some power less than $x^5$ and constants, do we take the upper bound $x^5$ to simplify and use only the upper bound in each product/term? If I've incorrectly used mathematical terms apologies.

Comment: Yes, this is something that you can do. In fact, in the above example, you're not interested in the value of M as long as it is just a finite number, since the result will be $O(x^4)$ whether you've found a bound with $M=13$ or managed to find a much tighter bound (which would be possible for some $x_0>1$). In practice, you won't be calculating this $M$ value any more as soon as you're sufficiently confident with the technique.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, thank you for the additional detail!

Answer (score 0):

We say $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if there $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|$. In your case $x^3=O(g(x))$, more is True, $x^3=o(g(x)), x>>1$ because

$$\dfrac{x^3}{x^4}\to 0, x\to \infty$$.

This is the reason on line 2.